# Properites of Lattices imply eachother.

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds, lattice-orders

Assume S is a finite poset.
A lattice is a poset S such that

1. S is bounded.
2. ∀ x, y ∈ S there exists x ∧ y (existence of Meet/Infimum).
3. ∀ x, y ∈ S there exists x ∨ y (existence of Join/Supremum).

**Exercise**: Check that any two of the three conditions above
implies the third one.

I'm particularly interested in the proof of:

S is bounded and for every two elements x, y ∈ S x ∧ y exists $\Rightarrow$ x ∨ y exists.

I know that the proof for this probably involves some kind of induction, but my last use of induction is a long time ago and I'm really desperate to get a proof for this implication.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The first condition is ***not*** implied by the other two. The lattice of integers $(\mathbb Z,\lt)$ is an example of an unbounded lattice.

Comment: Did you miss out the word ***finite***? Did you mean to type "A ***finite*** lattice is a ***finite*** poset $S$ such that"?

Comment: Yes that's true! The poset and lattice are both finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $S$ is bounded, finite, and $x \wedge y$ exists for every $x,y\in S$.

Let $a,b \in S$ and let us see that the least upper bound of $a$ and $b$, denoted $a \vee b$ exists in $S$.
Let $U$ denote the set of upper bounds of $a$ and $b$, that is,
$$U = \{ s \in S : a \leq s \;\&\; b \leq s \}.$$
Since $S$ is bounded, $U \neq \varnothing$, and since $U$ is finite, you can use an induction argument to show that $\bigwedge U$, the greatest lower bound of $U$, exists in $S$:
it's a matter of picking all the elements $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ of $U$ and compute $u_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge u_k$.

Now you can verify that $a \vee b = \bigwedge U$, that is, the least upper bound of $a$ and $b$ is the greatest lower bounds of their common upper bounds.